# How to set search page as home page

Tags: magento2, search

I would like to set search page `/catalogsearch/result/AVMP` as the home page. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set a redirect into .htaccess

steps :

- connect to FTP / SSH
- edit .htaccess file
- add folloing lines on the top

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ https://mywebsite.com/catalogsearch/result/AVMP [L,R=301]
```

or

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ https://mywebsite.com/catalogsearch/result/AVMP
```

Note: check & edit .htaccess of the DocumentRoot for your website because the website can run from Magento root or pub folder.

Comment: You got me wrong. I have to set it this way. When I go to the website: mywebsite.com then display this page: mywebsite.com/catalogsearch/result/AVMP

Comment: I have updated the answer 
kindly check and apply the same